# Can #endif in an included file be used to close a #if in the including file?

Tags: c, language-lawyer

Let's say I have two files, `a.h`:

```
#if 1
#include "b.h"
```

and `b.h`:

```
#endif
```

Both gcc's and clang's preprocessors reject `a.h`:

```
$ cpp -ansi -pedantic a.h >/dev/null
In file included from a.h:2:0:
b.h:1:2: error: #endif without #if
 #endif
  ^
a.h:1:0: error: unterminated #if
 #if 1
 ^
```

However, the C standard ([N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) **6.10.2.3**) says:

> A preprocessing directive of the form
>
> `# include "q-char-sequence" new-line`
>
> causes the replacement of that directive by the entire contents of the source file identified by the specified sequence between the `"` delimiters.

which appears to permit the construct above.

Are gcc and clang not compliant in rejecting my code?

Comment: Even if putting a `#if` in one file and the corresponding `#endif` in another were legal, it would IMHO be a bad idea.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The C standard defines 8 *translation phases*. A source file is processed by each of the 8 phases in sequence (or in an equivalent manner).

Phase 4, as defined in [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) section 5.1.1.2, is:

> Preprocessing directives are executed, macro invocations are expanded,
>   and **`_Pragma`** unary operator expressions are executed. If a
>   character sequence that matches the syntax of a universal character
>   name is produced by token concatenation (6.10.3.3), the behavior is
>   undefined. A **`#include`** preprocessing directive causes the named
>   header or source file to be processed from phase 1 through phase 4,
>   recursively. All preprocessing directives are then deleted.

The relevant sentence here is:

> A **`#include`** preprocessing directive causes the named
>   header or source file to be processed from phase 1 through phase 4,
>   recursively.

which implies that each included source file is preprocessed by itself. This precludes having a `#if` in one file and the corresponding `#endif` in another.

(As "A wild elephant" mentioned in comments, and as [rodrigo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32848810/827263) says, the grammar in section 6.10 also says that an *if-section*, which starts with a `#if` (or `#ifdef` or `#ifndef`) line and ends with a `#endif` line, can only appear as part of a *preprocessing-file*.)

Comment: Wonderful, thank you! If you're curious, what made me ask this is this paragraph from the Make manual: https://twitter.com/whitequark/status/648870461514850305

Comment: To put it another way `each included source file is processed through translation phase 4 before the including source file can complete phase 4`

Answer (score 10):

I think the compilers are right, or at best the standard is ambiguous.

The trick is not in how `#include` is implemented, but in the order in wich preprocessing is done.

Look at the grammar rules in section 6.10 of the C99 standard:

```
preprocessing-file:
    group[opt]

group:
    group-part
    group group-part

group-part:
    if-section
    control-line
    text-line
    # non-directive

if-section:
    if-group elif-groups[opt] else-group[opt] endif-line

if-group:
    # if constant-expression new-line group[opt]
...
control-line:
    # include pp-tokens new-line
    ...
```

As you can see, the `#include` stuff is nested inside the `group`, and `group` is the thing inside the `#if / #endif`.

For example, in a well-formed file such as:

```
#if 1
#include <a.h>
#endif
```

That will parse as `#if 1`, plus a `group`, plus `#endif`. And the inside `group` has an `#include`.

But in your example:

```
#if 1
#include <a.h>
```

The rule `if-section` does not apply to this source, so the `group` productions are not even checked.

Probably you can argue that the standard is ambiguous, because it does not specify when the replacement of the `#include` directive happen, and that a conforming implementation could shift a lot of grammar rules and replace the `#include` before failing for not finding the `#endif`. But these ambiguities are impossible to avoid if the side effects of the syntax modify the text you are parsing. Isn't C wonderful?

Comment: Ah, this is a good point as well. Wish I could accept two answers!

Answer (score 0):

Thinking of a C preprocessor as a very simple compiler, to translate a file a C preprocessor conceptually carries out a few phases.

1. **Lexical analysis** – Groups the sequence of characters making up the preprocessing translation unit into strings having an identified meaning (**tokens**) in the preprocessor language.
2. **Syntactic analysis** – Groups the tokens of the  preprocessing translation unit into syntactic structures built according to the preprocessing language grammar.
3. **Code generation** – Translates all files making up the preprocessing translation unit into a single file containing 'pure' C instructions only.

Strictly speaking, the translation phases mentioned in §5.1.1.2 of the [C Standard (ISO/IEC 9899:201x)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) relating to preprocessing are phase 3 and phase 4. Phase 3 corresponds almost exactly to lexical analysis while phase 4 is about code generation.

Syntactic analysis (parsing) seems to be missing from that picture. Indeed, the C preprocessor grammar is so simple that real preprocessors/compilers perform it along with lexical analysis.

If the syntactic analysis phase ends successfully – i.e. all statements in the preprocessing translation unit are legal according to the preprocessor grammar – code generation can take place and all preprocessing directives are executed.
Executing a preprocessing directive means  to transform the source file according to the its semantics and then removing the directive from the source file.
The semantics for each preprocessor directive is specified in §6.10.1-6.10.9 of the C Standard.

Getting back to your sample program, the 2 files you provided, i.e. `a.h` and `b.h`, are conceptually processed as follows.

***Lexical Analysis*** - Each individual preprocessing token is delimited by a '{' on the left and a '}' on the right.

`a.h`

```
{#}{if} {1}
{#}{include} {"b.h"}
```

`b.h`

```
{#}{endif}
```

This phase is performed without errors and its result, the sequence of preprocessing tokens, is passed to the subsequent phase: syntactic analysis.

***Syntactic Analysis***

A tentative derivation for a.h is given below

```
preprocessing-file →
group →
group-part →
if-section →
if-group endif-line → 
if-group #endif new-line →
…
```

and it is clear that the contents of a.h cannot be derived from the preprocessing grammar – in fact the terminating `#endif` is missing – and therefore `a.h` is not syntactically correct. This is exactly what your compiler is telling you when it writes

```
a.h:1:0: error: unterminated #if
```

Something similar happens for `b.h`; reasoning backwards, the `#endif` can only be derived from the rule

```
if-section → 
if-group elif-groups[opt] else-group[opt] endif-line
```

This means the file contents should be derived from one of the following 3 groups

```
# if constant-expression new-line group[opt]
# ifdef identifier new-line group[opt]
# ifndef identifier new-line group[opt]
```

Since it is not the case, because `b.h` does not contain `# if/# ifdef/# ifndef` but only the single `#endif` line, again the contents of `b.h` is not syntactically  correct and your compiler tells you about that this way

```
In file included from a.h:2:0:
b.h:1:2: error: #endif without #if
```

***Code Generation***

Of course, since your program is lexically sound but syntactically not correct, this phase never gets performed.

Answer (score -2):

```
#if / #ifdef / #ifndef
#elif
#else
#endif
```

must be matched within one file.

Comment: Since the C language is defined by the C standard, can you point out where the C standard requires this? I could not find such a requirement stated anywhere.

Comment: @whitequark Well the if-section rule of the syntax described in 6.10 requires this.

Comment: @Awildelephant can you be more precise? The section 6.10.1.6 only says that the corresponding group(s) are skipped; it does not mention files. E.g. in `all the groups until the #endif are skipped`.

Comment: @KeithThompson Congrats on finding the relevant information in the document, but I'm still skeptical about your comment... I think I don't understand what you mean by syntactic construct. Syntactic analysis is done before anything that I know of, including executing preprocessing directives. If parsing fails, because the #endif is missing for example and no rule can be matched, nothing can be done and the world stops.

Comment: @KeithThompson The fact that a rule doesn't use terminals doesn't mean it can be cut. The only way to match an `#if` was to go through the if-section rule, which requires it to be followed by an `#endif`. Thus, the syntax alone justify the compilers' behavior.

Comment: @Awildelephant: You're absolutely correct. I misread the grammar. The "single syntactic construct" that I was missing is the *if-section* non-terminal. I've deleted my earlier incorrect comments.